# res.render - passing parameters dynamically

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to render dynamically depending on a number of parameters in an object. Let's create a JSON example

```
var json =
[
    {   
        "param_1":11,
        "param_2":22
    },
    {
        "param_1":33,
        "param_2":44
    }
]
```

And here is how I would pass the parameters if var json was static:

```
res.render("template.hbs", {
item_0_param_1: json[0].param_1
item_0_param_2: json[0].param_2,
item_1_param_1: json[1].param_1
item_1_param_2: json[1].param_2
}
```

The question that I have is - how can I pass parameters from variable 'json' if it is not static? I was thinking about doing a loop inside render, but I didn't know how would I return assigned parameters. Would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: How about making the loop *before* the `res.render`, create an object with what you got in the loop, then pass it to `res.render`?

Comment: You can just pass the whole dynamic array as an item inside an object you pass to `res.render()` and then let the template iterate whatever array is there.  But, the template has to know in advance what type of data to expect, it just doesn't need to know how long an array is (you can use array iteration features in the template langauge).

Comment: Got it! I never tried to loop through an object using templating language but that's the solution for this must be. Will check the documentation and figure it out! thanks again